# I need to make my text adapt on a Card in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, text, frontend

I'm trying to make the text at the bottom of the cards (number of viewers and video Time) always be at the bottom whether there are one or two lines of text above it.

This shows my issue: [image]

React code:

```
import React from 'react'
import'./Cards.css'


export const Cards = ({streamer, title, avatar, description}) => {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="card-container">
      <img src={streamer}
      alt='Card Image'
      className="card-img"
      />
      <h2 className="card-title">{title}</h2>
        <img className="card-profileImg" src={avatar} />
      <p className="card-description">
        {description}
      </p>
    </div>
    </> 
  )
}

export default Cards
```

CSS

```
.card-container {
    width: 30rem;
    border-radius: 0 0 2rem 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px #999;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: #3473EC;
    height: 275px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    
    
}

.card-img {
    width: 98.75%;
    border: 3px solid #ff636d;
    border-bottom: 0;
    height: 175px;
  
}

.card-title {
   margin-left: 6rem;
   margin-top: 0.75rem;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;

}

.card-description {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 6rem;
    margin-top: -2px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: bottom;
    
}

.card-profileImg {
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: -65px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you could use ```position: absolute;  bottom: _px;``` within the card to adjust it a certain distance from the bottom.

Comment: Also, if you wanna use Stack Overflow it's important to check out the SO [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Thank you I didn't know "position: absolute;" worked this way, i'm checking the CoC right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this for your cards css:

```
position: absolute;  
bottom: 0;
```

In your CSS:

```
.card-container {
    width: 30rem;
    border-radius: 0 0 2rem 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px #999;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: #3473EC;
    height: 275px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative; /* took out display: flex; added relative positioning  */
}

.card-description {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 6rem;
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px; /* Or whatever distance looks good */
}
```

Comment: @Allan, If this answer worked for you, please consider giving it an upvote.